# How to extract data from a file and create a table of objects java?

Tags: java, arrays, tabs

Hey i was wondering how can i create a table of  objects in java using a text file
I've created my table

```
Table tab[] = new Table[6]
```

and here's my text file :

```
id|des|pr

50 | Internet Fibre 50                          | 40.00

150| Internet Fibre 150                         | 50.00

500| Internet Fibre 500                         | 90.00

B  | Forfait Bien                               | 60.00

T  | Forfait Très Bien                          | 40.00

E  | Forfait Excellent                          | 30.00
```

I've created my table

```
Table tab[] = new Table[6]
```

I'd like to read each line (except the first line ) and make it an object (the type is Table) in the table above (tab) by sperating the "|" on each line so i'll have 6 objects in total each one will follow this constructor

```
Table newTable = new Table(id , des , pr);
```

Thanx !

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

**Main.java**

```
    Table[] tabs = new Table[6];
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File location")); // add your file location here
    bufferedReader.readLine(); // ignoring the header line
    String row = bufferedReader.readLine();
    int count = 0;
    while (row != null) {
        String[] split = row.split("\\|");
        tabs[count]  = new Table(split[0].trim().replace("\\t", ""), split[1].trim().replace("\\t", ""), Double.parseDouble(split[2].trim().replace("\\t", "")));
        count++;
        row = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
```

**Table.java**

```
public class Table {
    private String id;
    private String des;
    private double price;

    public Table(String id, String des, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.des = des;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDes() {
        return des;
    }

    public void setDes(String des) {
        this.des = des;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Table{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", des='" + des + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur answer ! but it didn't work for me i tried to catch the exceptions but still didn't work. Did u try it urself ?

Comment: Add the exception

Comment: i added it but still didn't work

Comment: I mean add the stack trace of the exception that you are getting.